# Is There A way to call API that retrieve company info from quickbooks

Tags: c#

i am new to mvc trying to call Api from Quickbooks to get company info (Sandbox), i followed the instructions in intuit.com about that : create app , generate client id , client secret and use them in the web.config . also i generate OAuth2 and i was able to see the 'connect to Quickbooks ' dialog in my project after sign in with user name and password , now i was trying to call the Api so firstly i create dobject of OAuth2RequestValidator class but an error says 'Object Reference Not Set to instance of an object' a i am using claims for authentication i think that claimsPrincipal is not able to read claims from ClaimsIdentity and i am stuck here , i am trying to use the sample code that is in intuit.com

this is the controller to get authentication and call the api

```
public class AppController : Controller
{
    public static string clientid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientid"];
    public static string clientsecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientsecret"];
    public static string redirectUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["redirectUrl"];
    public static string environment = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appEnvironment"];

    public static OAuth2Client auth2Client = new OAuth2Client(clientid, clientsecret, redirectUrl, environment);

    /// <summary>
    /// Use the Index page of App controller to get all endpoints from discovery url
    /// </summary>
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        Session.Clear();
        Session.Abandon();
        Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut("Cookies");
        return View();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Start Auth flow
    /// </summary>
    public ActionResult InitiateAuth(string submitButton)
    {
        switch (submitButton)
        {
            case "Connect to QuickBooks":
                List<OidcScopes> scopes = new List<OidcScopes>();
                scopes.Add(OidcScopes.Accounting);
                string authorizeUrl = auth2Client.GetAuthorizationURL(scopes);
                return Redirect(authorizeUrl);
            default:
                return (View());
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// QBO API Request
    /// </summary>
    public ActionResult ApiCallService()
    {
        if (Session["realmId"] != null)
        {
            string realmId = Session["realmId"].ToString();
            try
            {
                var principal = User as ClaimsPrincipal;
                OAuth2RequestValidator oauthValidator = new OAuth2RequestValidator(principal.FindFirst("access_token").Value);

                // Create a ServiceContext with Auth tokens and realmId
                ServiceContext serviceContext = new ServiceContext(realmId, IntuitServicesType.QBO, oauthValidator);
                serviceContext.IppConfiguration.MinorVersion.Qbo = "23";

                // Create a QuickBooks QueryService using ServiceContext
                QueryService<CompanyInfo> querySvc = new QueryService<CompanyInfo>(serviceContext);
                CompanyInfo companyInfo = querySvc.ExecuteIdsQuery("SELECT * FROM CompanyInfo").FirstOrDefault();

                string output = "Company Name: " + companyInfo.CompanyName + " Company Address: " + companyInfo.CompanyAddr.Line1 + ", " + companyInfo.CompanyAddr.City + ", " + companyInfo.CompanyAddr.Country + " " + companyInfo.CompanyAddr.PostalCode;
                return View("ApiCallService", (object)("QBO API call Successful!! Response: " + output));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return View("ApiCallService", (object)("QBO API call Failed!" + " Error message: " + ex.Message));
            }
        }
        else
            return View("ApiCallService", (object)"QBO API call Failed!");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Use the Index page of App controller to get all endpoints from discovery url
    /// </summary>
    public ActionResult Error()
    {
        return View("Error");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Action that takes redirection from Callback URL
    /// </summary>
    public ActionResult Tokens()
    {
        return View("Tokens");
    }
```

and this controller created Access Token and refresh token

```
public class CallbackController : Controller
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Code and realmid/company id recieved on Index page after redirect is complete from Authorization url
    /// </summary>
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        //Sync the state info and update if it is not the same
        var state = Request.QueryString["state"];
        if (state.Equals(AppController.auth2Client.CSRFToken, StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            ViewBag.State = state + " (valid)";
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.State = state + " (invalid)";
        }

        string code = Request.QueryString["code"] ?? "none";
        string realmId = Request.QueryString["realmId"] ?? "none";
        await GetAuthTokensAsync(code, realmId);

        ViewBag.Error = Request.QueryString["error"] ?? "none";

        return RedirectToAction("Tokens", "App");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Exchange Auth code with Auth Access and Refresh tokens and add them to Claim list
    /// </summary>
    private async Task GetAuthTokensAsync(string code, string realmId)
    {
        if (realmId != null)
        {
            Session["realmId"] = realmId;
        }

        Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut("TempState");
        var tokenResponse = await AppController.auth2Client.GetBearerTokenAsync(code);

        var claims = new List<Claim>();

        if (Session["realmId"] != null)
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim("realmId", Session["realmId"].ToString()));
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tokenResponse.AccessToken))
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim("access_token", tokenResponse.AccessToken));
            claims.Add(new Claim("access_token_expires_at", (DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(tokenResponse.AccessTokenExpiresIn)).ToString()));
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tokenResponse.RefreshToken))
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim("refresh_token", tokenResponse.RefreshToken));
            claims.Add(new Claim("refresh_token_expires_at", (DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(tokenResponse.RefreshTokenExpiresIn)).ToString()));
        }

        var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Cookies");
        Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(id);

    }
}
```

note : this is the controller where the user redirected after authentication completed .

and this is the error occured when i try to call api 
bject reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

> Line 66:                 //{ Line 67:                     var
>   principal = User as ClaimsPrincipal; Line 68:
>   OAuth2RequestValidator oauthValidator = new
>   OAuth2RequestValidator(principal.FindFirst("access_token").Value);
>   Line 69:  Line 70:                     // Create a ServiceContext with
>   Auth tokens and realmId

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this and found a solution, might be able to save someone else some time.

IntuitAPI docs make the assumption that you are using Cookie Authentication

Add this to Startup.cs then give it a try

```
       app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
       {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
       });

       app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
       {
           AuthenticationType = "TempState",
           AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive
       });
```